# Expressing numbers in scientific notation

Tags: translation, number

I assume that scientific discussion in Chinese uses scientific notation, such as 5×10<sup>12</sup>. How would I read such a number aloud?

I looked at the [rules for saying numbers](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/147/rules-for-saying-numbers), as well as the [Wikipedia page it links to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_numerals). The closest thing I could find were the large numbers and metric prefixes.

If I follow the large numbers, then I would guess 五兆, but I'm hoping there's a more general phrase like the way we say, "five times ten to the twelfth power" in English. I found that 乘幂 means exponentiation, so can I say 五倍十二乘幂的十?

Comment: There is a regional difference here -- 兆 is only 10^6 (million) in mainland China while 10^12 in Taiwan...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

五 乘以 十的 十二次冪
Five times 10 to the 12.

Answer (score 2):

OR "五乘以十的十二次方"

(Chinese StackExchange complained "Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 14" Hence this useless filler...)